# Ubuntu 16.04 server is listening but not accepting incoming requests

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, ping, connection, ubuntu-16.04

I recently upgraded my server from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. The upgrade seemed successful (so I'm not sure if it's related) but about a week in I restarted the host and it now will not accept remote requests.

I can connect to the terminal using my hosting provider's console access but I can't remotely SSH into the machine. Once in the machine I can ping myhost.com successfully, but I cannot ping the machine from a remote location. Pinging from my development machine requests in `Request timed out`.

I tried a previous loading a previous snapshot from before I upgraded my OS and I can ping the machine successfully.

I've tried tailing `/var/log/auth.log` but the log is not updated when I try to access remotely.

I'm not sure what to try next to find out why my server is not responding.

**EDIT**

Running `iptables -nvL` results in:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Comment: Can you check the local firewall rules to make sure that inbound connections are allowed? Perhaps `iptables -nvL`

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-image-\`uname -r\` &&
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-\`uname -r\`

Comment: Thanks @Tolsadus, it looks like I also can't ping remote hosts from inside the machine so I can't call download anything from the apt-get repositories

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot you can do, but also a lot of things that can be the problem. Unfortunately what you have related points in two different directions.

Since this happened after a system upgrade and reboot, I think it may be possible that your services are not started.

Execute `sudo netstat --tcp -l`. There should be a line like this:

```
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                    *:*                     LISTEN
```

If there isn't, then your ssh server is not listening. Execute `sudo service ssh restart`. If that fixes the problem, check your runlevels and make ssh is started on boot.

If there is, then there may be a network problem (and a ping timeout certainly points in that direction), but `iptables -nvL` should show that if it was on the system, and it doesn't.

Hmm I just saw your comment saying that you couldn't get out, it now seems more probable that you have a general network problem.

You need the output of `ifconfig -a` to check that your public IP is in there. If it is, you need the output of `route -n` to check that you do have a default route outwards (I think this may be the problem, and almost certainly if you can contact other machines in your subnet but not outside machines).

Comment: I have ensured that ssh and other services are running but my public IP is not appearing anywhere in the output of `ifconfig -a`

Comment: That *can* be normal, if you are running in a hosting provider's cloud with destination NAT. You should compare to your other machines, and if that doesn't help you should contact your hosting provider (you haven't named it).